# How to take input from a file and redirect the output of that input to another file

Tags: linux

Lets say I have 2 files -file1 and file2
file2 is empty and file1 has ls-l in it, so how can I take the ls-l from file1 to the terminal and output its content to file2

Comment: Homework? If so, at least demonstrate that you've *tried* to come up with an answer yourself.

Comment: It sounds like using `cp file1 file2` is not what you're looking for, but that's a very obvious way to take the contents of `file1` and 'output' those contents to `file2`.  If you explain in more detail, perhaps we'll understand how a simple file copy isn't the right answer.

Comment: Your question needs more info, even a response has "vague" and "looks like homework". Show the community you tried something, and tell them more about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is rather vague, to say the least.

What I take from it: you want to see the content of file1 on screen and put it into file2 in one step.

```
tee file2 <file1
```